# What kind of exception should you use for DX11 runtime exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I'm creating a 3D renderer in DirectX 11 and I'm trying to build an error handler for exceptions.

I'm using the built in HRESULTS now that DX is integrated into the main OS in combination with the D3D debug layer. My problem is the following line of code:

`m_contextPtr->Draw(3u,0u);`

Figuring out what the exceptions themselves are isn't the issue here but getting a try catch block to throw so I can display them on screen is proving to be an issue.

The full code:

```
try
    {
        m_contextPtr->Draw(3u,0u);
    }
    catch(std::runtime_error &e)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, e.what(), "Runtime Exception", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    catch(GPUErrorHandler& e)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, e.what(), "DX Exception", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    catch(ErrorHandler& e)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, e.what(), "Win32 Exception", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, e.what(), "Standard Exception", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "No details available", "Unknown Exception", MB_OK|MB_ICONQUESTION);
    }
```

The custom error classes are derived from std::exception appropriate to the type of exception that is thrown.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the current behavior of that code?

Comment: Currently I get this unhandled exception:
`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCBF90A839 (KernelBase.dll) in DX11 Graphics Engine.exe: 0x0000087A (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000BFCD8FBF80, 0x000000BFCD8FDD70).`